# access each element in a data set from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to access each element in a data set from javascript. I want to do something like the following in my javascript.

```
for(var i = 0; i < @Model.saVM.mapDetails.Count; i++){
        var data = @Model.saVM.mapDetails;
        alert(data[i]);
}
```

But i keep getting this error

> Unterminated template literal

Other things i have tried..

```
for(var i = 0; i < @Model.saVM.mapDetails.Count; i++){
        var data = @Model.saVM.mapDetails.ElementAt(i);

}
```

AND

```
for(var i = 0; i < @Model.saVM.mapDetails.Count; i++){
        var data = @Model.saVM.mapDetails.ElementAt(@:i);

}
```

**Here is why i need to do this**

I have an MVC application that binds data from Model into an html table. The number of rows and columns are variable depending on the data in Model.

```
public class StudentAssessmentViewModel
{
    public StudentAssessmentViewModel() { }
    public List<ShortResult> results { get; set; }        
    public List<ShortStudent> students {get; set;}
    public List<MapDetail> mapDetails { get; set; }
    public List<ResultType> resultTypes { get; set; }        
    public List<ShortResult> calculatedResults { get; set; }
    public List<Mean> means { get; set; } 
}
```

now in this table, when i create a td, i check if there is value and color in Model.results (that matches current student (in row) AND current Header (in column)) to be put in current td, if yes then put the value and color else move forward i.e. create next td.

Then i converted this table into a kendo grid, which preserved the td values but removed all the colors.

So now i have to separately parse results list and again assign colors to each cell in kendogrid.

Comment: You can't mix ASP.NET Razor with JavaScript. One is server-side rendering and the other client-side.

Comment: then how do i access each of these values?

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop within Razor code.

Comment: that's a limitation

Comment: You need to first store whole modal in varible , then do loop over it

Comment: @Asif, can u share some code to do that?

Comment: Just Wait - i'm testing my code

Comment: alternatively i have also tried to parse var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.saVM.mapDetails)); How can i parse it?

Comment: NO Luck with @html.Raw ?

Comment: i have html.raw as {object object},{object object} but how do i access each object's particular property in a loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144884/discussion-between-asif-raza-and-samra).

Comment: YOu need to loop over it {object object},{object object}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop you need to do as below:

```
<script>
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.saVM.mapDetails));
$(model).each(function (index, item) {
        console.log(item.MapId);
        console.log(item.MapName});
</script>
```

Assuming you have MapId and MapName properties in mapDetails. Hope it helps.

Comment: That was awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: If my model data is refreshed, the model object in javascript is not changed :S..how to update it?

Answer (score 2):

I have make simple example , hope it will help you

View

```
      @model  IEnumerable<JqueryAjaxClientProject.Models.Details> 


@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>modalPassTOjavascirpt</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))'
            console.log(model)
            if (model != null) {

                //loop over the model
            }
            });

    </script>

</body>
```

Controller:

```
  public List<Details> getCollection () {

        List<Details> obe = new  List<Details>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Details obj = new Details();
            obj.Id = 1;
            obj.name = "nae";

            obe.Add(obj);
        }
        
        return obe;
    }

    public ActionResult modalPassTOjavascirpt() {

        var get = getCollection();

        return View(get);
    }
```

Output [image]

**Updated**

JS/script

```
  var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'
           //   console.log(model)

            if (model != null) {
                
                $.each(JSON.parse(model), function (i, data) {

                    var row = data;
                    console.log(row);
                });
            
            }
            });
```

OUTPUT [image]

Comment: how do u loop over the model? i am trying model[i] and it returns [Object object] not a json string

Comment: Thanks Asif. this was really helpful although i have marked another answer both answers are correct.